# Why am I able to access my webapp publicly even when blocking the port in my Linode?

Tags: docker, security, firewall, traefik, linode

I have a Linode setup and I've setup UFW to block ports, particularly 8080. I've reloaded the firewall
and I'm still able to access the webapp through the web.

UFW:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
787/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       DENY        Anywhere
787/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  DENY        Anywhere (v6)
```

I am running traefik on docker, and have the dashboard on port mapped to 8080 and am able to access the app via web. What is happening here? Isn't the rule for 8080 supposed to block the connection?

**Solution:**

Edit the daemon.json found in /etc/docker/daemon.json and add the following:

```
{ "iptables": false }
```

Save, and reload docker. This now prevents docker from modifying iptables and "sidestepping" ufw rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to ports opened via Docker port publishing is controlled either in the `nat` `PREROUTING` chain or in the `filter` `FORWARD` table. It's likely that your existing firewall rules are only affecting the `filter` `INPUT` table.

The canonical place to add rules for mediating access to Docker containers is `DOCKER_USER` chain in the `filter` table, which is called from the `FORWARD` chain.

For rules in the `DOCKER_USER` chain, you will need to use the port on which the container is listening, not the host port on which the service is published.

Comment: So the true way to block a port is not modifying ufw rules? Should I be looking into iptables and making changes there? Never worked on modify anything there.

Comment: Well, "ufw" is just a wrapper over "iptables". If you can convince ufw to place rules in the `FORWARD` chain, you can probably use it. I'm not familiar with ufw and can't provide direction in that regard.

Comment: Posted solution. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Cheers.